# Get the high of 4hr candle from 15m chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My indicator is running on the 15 minute chart and I need to get the high of a previous 4hr candle. I have similar code working at the start that works fine. However this one section is giving me a compile error, not code is highlighted red. The 4hr candle I am looking for is `high[2]`. It is this that is causing the error `request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", high[2])` If I replace with just `high[2]` then there is no error

My code is:

```
if filteredtopf
    current_fractal_high := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", high[2])
    current_fractal_high_index := bar_index-2
    if range_high == high[2]
        range_high_fractal := true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because it was inside an `if` statement. I removed from there and placed inside a function which I then call from the `if`